# Select works in Sqlite Database but Insert and Update statements do not

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite, insert

I am using sqlite database with qt in development environment and It works perfectly fine (inserting and updating records) but when I use the same database file (copied from development environment) after deployment, insertion, deletion and updation give error while database gets populated all right. What can possibly be wrong? Do database files work after copying them to different location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the errors you get? Consider posting some code, too.

Comment: I do not have the code right now but to be honest, I only made boolean check on db.exec() call. More over I am very new to qt. Is there anyway to check to check actual error instead of only getting true or false?

Comment: There's `lastError()` where you can get a string description of the error. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqlquery.html#lastError

Comment: Ok I will try that and get back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So It is kind of solved. The restriction is that Windows 7 wont let you change files in C drive where the program is installed. It recommends to put these kind of files in Application data folder or in User home like My Documents etc.